# open_CV contrib Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, opencv, opencv-contrib

I'm looking to apply SLIC algorithm on an image. I have open_CV integrated with Android Studio but I'm stuck in how to integrate openCV_contrib with Android Studio on Windows machine? I couldn't find how to do it.